# How to remove Giacomini plastic radiator valve head?

Tags: plumbing, valve, radiator

[image: radiator valve]

I want to remove the white plastic valve head (so I can replace it with a smart wi-fi controlled one), but I can't figure out how. Simply pulling it doesn't work.

Edit! I managed to get the top part off, but the bottom part still refuses to budge. Picture below:

[image]

Comment: The smaller plastic ring looks like a locking ring.  Pull it into the big one and it should turn.

Comment: @crip659 I actually managed to get the big/top part off, but now the bottom part (which I think you meant was the plastic ring) refuses to budge still. I put a new picture in my original post of it.

Comment: Was not expecting that.

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer? Is there a model number anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that plastic under collar is just a friction fit on. The actual valve body is metal.

Try levering with several small screwdrivers from the pipe direction - you want to stretch the collar a bit so it pops off the ridge holding it on. You can see the slots in the base - they subdivide the base into 2/3/4/? parts and you need at least one screwdriver per part.

When I fitted smart heads to my Giacomini valves, Hive UK would send out free Giacomini to Hive adapters: I didn’t use the Hive system, but their adapters fitted my alternative brand of smart heads.